# How to use a generic type annotation inside a function in Facebook Flow

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

Is is possible to use Flow's generic type annotation inside a function?  For example, to filter items based on whether they are of the generic type.

```
// @flow
class Base {}

function filterItems<T>(items: Base[]) {
  return items.filter(x => /* How to filter for 'x is T' here?*/);
}
```

So, the outcome of the following code, `a` would be an array containing a single `Foo`.

```
class Foo extends Base {}
const a = filter<Foo>([new Base(), new Foo()]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flowtype is an annotation-only syntax. Converting Flowtype code to JavaScript only involves deleting the annotations. This means that what you're asking is not possible, because the types do not exist at runtime.

To do what you want, I'd recommend just doing normal JS like this:

```
function filter<T: Base>(type: Class<T>, items: Array<Base>): Array<T> {
  return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item instanceof type) acc.push(item);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

and

```
const a = filter(Foo, [new Base(), new Foo()]);
```

Comment: Thank you - thought I was trying to put a square peg into a round hole!